# Jetpack compose navigation crash when adding arguments to route with repeated NavType?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, jetpack-compose-navigation

I am getting following crash error message

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Query parameter  must only be present once in android-app://androidx.navigation/page_detail?arg1={arg1}. To support repeated query parameters, use an array type for your argument and the pattern provided in your URI will be used to parse each query parameter instance.
```

And this is arguments

```
val arguments = listOf(
        navArgument(KEY_1){
            defaultValue = ""
            type = NavType.StringType
        },
        navArgument(KEY_2){
            defaultValue = ""
            type = NavType.StringType
        },
        navArgument(KEY_3){
            defaultValue = ""
            type = NavType.StringType
        },
        navArgument(KEY_5){
            defaultValue = -1
            type = NavType.LongType
        }
    )
```

This error happens only when I repeat the NavType more than twice eg NavType.StringType

Comment: The two spaces in `Query parameter  must` indicates that one of your keys is an empty string.

Comment: Can't I send empty value ? @ianhanniballake

Answer (score 0):

The problem was sending empty string value for two or more arguments value so if arg value is empty make sure some default text like "-1".